# How to change string to React Native Component?

Tags: react-native

I have a react native component string.

const str = '<View style={{'width':200, 'height':50, 'backgroundColor':'blue'}}>';

I want to change this string to react native element. I render this string like this.

```
<Text>{str}</Text>
```

It is returning only text.

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Yyij.png)

Actually, I want the result like this. How to convert the string element to react native component?

[expect result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNy5n.png)

Comment: Everything between `Text` component is rendered as plain text. Why you wanna do this?

Comment: I am beginner in react native. I am trying to make custom component and I want to support React native component and show it correctly in mobile. But I have a string properties in json and I want to change like a React native format style. It is only return 'string' format in my emulator. It is little complicated and I just want to know is it possilbe to change string to React Native.

Comment: There's probably a much better and safer alternative to this. Can you make your data into a json array and have React Native render it based on the type in the json?

Comment: @Abe, i donot understand, can you show me some example?

Comment: `[{text: 'text1', color: 'red'}, {text: 'text2', color: 'blue'}].map(item => <Text style={{ color: item.color }}>{item.text}</Text>` - oversimplified, but you could do something like this instead

Answer (score -1):

You can use React Native WebView.

```
<WebView
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    source={{ html: str }}
/>
```

https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview

Comment: edited. thanks I thought it was reactjs.